# trying to get my nested recyclerView to be scrollable when I have an ItemTouchHelper attached to the main Recycler

Tags: android, kotlin, scroll, nested, touch

https://streamable.com/2eml8r

you can see it in the video.
I can't find a way to intercept the input touch events going to the ItemTouchHelper

```
class SwipeToDelete(var thoughtsAdapter: ThoughtsAdapter) : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,` 
ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
override fun onMove(
    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
    viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
    target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
): Boolean {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}
   

 override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        var adapterListPosition = viewHolder.adapterPosition
        thoughtsAdapter.deleteItem(adapterListPosition)
    }

}
class SwipeToSpread(var thoughtsAdapter: ThoughtsAdapter, val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel) : 
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
    override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: 
RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
    var adapterListPosition = viewHolder.adapterPosition
    //TabButton.currentlyActive.value = sharedViewModel.spreadTabButton
    sharedViewModel.thoughtsTabButton.performClick()
}
}
```

the item of the outer recycler where the sidescrolling recycler is nested

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
    <variable
        name="thought"
        type="seri.dnair.items.Thought"/>

    <variable
        name="clickThought"
        type="seri.dnair.adapter_tabs.ThoughtsClickListener" />

</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/thought_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:onClick="@{() -> clickThought.onClick(thought)}">

    <seri.dnair.utils.OrientationAwareRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/subStrainRecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:animationCache="false"
        android:background="@drawable/thoughtgreenbg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thoughtDivider"
        android:layout_width="417dp"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dividerbar" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/thought_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subStrainRecycler"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:thoughtContent="@{thought}" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/brainButton"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/brainbutton" />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

snippet of the Fragment this takes place in:

```
    // FUNCTION values for the adapter
    val selectStrain = StrainsClickListener { strain -> thoughtsViewModel.selectStrain(strain)}
    val thoughtsAdapter = ThoughtsAdapter(thoughtsViewModel, thoughtsViewModel.selectedNote 
,clickSelectThought, clickSubStrainListener, imm, userDatabaseDao)
    val thoughtStrainAdapter = ThoughtStrainsAdapter(selectStrain, thoughtsViewModel.activeStrain, 
thoughtsViewModel, imm)

    // Function passed to the ItemTouchHelper to tell it what to do on swipe left
    val itemSwipeLeftThoughtHelper = ItemTouchHelper(SwipeToDelete(thoughtsAdapter))
    // attached the itemTouchHelper that is responsible for swipe left delete to the thoughtsAdapter
    itemSwipeLeftThoughtHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.thoughtsRecycler)

    // Swipe Right attached to the thoughtsRecycler to go to spread
    val itemSwipeRightThoughtHelper = ItemTouchHelper(SwipeToSpread(thoughtsAdapter, 
sharedViewModel))
    itemSwipeRightThoughtHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.thoughtsRecycler)

    binding.sharedViewModel = sharedViewModel
    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    binding.thoughtsViewModel = thoughtsViewModel
    binding.thoughtsRecycler.adapter = thoughtsAdapter
    binding.strainsBar.adapter = thoughtStrainAdapter
```

snippet of the inside the adapter class of the outer recycler

```
   val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(thoughtHolder.itemView.context, 
LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false )
        val subStrainRecycler = thoughtHolder.itemView.findViewById<RecyclerView> 
   (R.id.subStrainRecycler)
        val editButton = thoughtHolder.itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.brainButton)
        val thoughtContent = thoughtHolder.itemView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.thought_content)
        editButton.setOnClickListener { thoughtsViewModel.changeScreenFromBtn()}

        val subStrainsAdapter = SubStrainsAdapter(thoughtsViewModel, clickSubStrain, imm, 
    thoughtItem.id, thoughtItem.strainName)
        subStrainRecycler.adapter = subStrainsAdapter
        subStrainRecycler.layoutManager = layoutManager
        subStrainsAdapter.addHeaderAndSubmitList(null)
```

the custom recycler class i just copy&pasted the code for in search for a solution:
https://pastebin.com/cywUWRZG

does not work but also hasn't done any harm as i can see

I really want this to work. id redo the whole thing